# CSS3 calc() doesn't work with position fixed/absolute

Tags: css, css-position

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

I'm trying to calculate width of a div :

```
#container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
    width: calc(100% - 1em);
    padding: .5em;
}
```

Comment: I can not answer your question, but please note that it's a lot easier to help you if you post your code and elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT 2:

This is the version for Webkit browsers (as asked in comments), tested with the latest release of Chrome, and fully working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HvVst/1/

used `-webkit-calc()` instead of `calc()`.

---

EDIT: Then you have to subtract the 1px borders to the 0.5em padding, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/HvVst/

HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
   FIXED HEADER
</div>
<div id="main">
    normal div
    <br/>
    Sample Text 1
    <br/>
    Sample Text 2
    <br/>
    Sample Text 3
    <br/>
    Sample Text 4
    <br/>
    Sample Text 5
    <br/>
    Sample Text 6
    <br/>
    Sample Text 7
    <br/>
    Sample Text 8
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#banner{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    background: #fff;
    width: calc(100% - 1em);
    padding: calc(0.5em - 1px); /* <-- THIS ONE !!*/
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
}

#main{
    margin-top: calc(50px + 1em);
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 500px;
}
```

---

It works with position fixed/absolute, but (if no relative parents specified for absolute, and always for fixed) it refers to the window width, not to the container width.

(100% - 1em) = 100% of the window excluding the scrollbar...

what are you trying to achieve ?

If you want position absolute in the parent's boundaries, set the parent to position:relative...

Comment: I want that div to be 100% width and I need to minus 1em of padding, so it won't overflow body, if that makes sense. It has to be fixed as well, because I want it to sit on the top of the page. There is no point to set parent element to relative position in this case.

Comment: It looks like webkit browsers doesn't works with this. Thank you! P.s. Sorry, can't vote up your answer while I'm new here.

Comment: Sorry i tested it with Firefox, you didn't mention "Webkit browsers" :)
For webkit browsers, just use "-webkit-calc(100% - 1em);" instead of "calc(100% - 1em);", do the substitution for every calc() used. 
You can't vote up but you can still mark as Accepted Answer, if you think it is the right answer.

Comment: I've tried -webkit-calc(), but no luck. Hopefully it will be supported in near future :) for now jQuery will help

Comment: Mmm... what are you using ? I've not Chrome nor Safari installed so i can't try, btw you can test -webkit-calc here: http://peter.sh/files/calc.html.
Maybe it doesn't fully support subtractions, but it seems strange to me.

Comment: I've edited the answer, i tested it with chrome and it works :)